# React - API data only showing if I manually refresh the page

Tags: reactjs, axios, react-hooks

I'm new to React and I created a small admin panel where you can add, edit, remove products. I would like to display 3 products from API when someone opens the app the first time and don't have edited products yet, but this data only shows if I manually refresh the page. I only want to display that if edited product is false, but initially I set edited products to false yet somehow it's not displaying, though I see the data as well as edited is set to false in the console.

Demo
https://react-storeadminpanel.herokuapp.com/

Here is the related code:

```
const Products = () => {
    const {products, setProducts, setAllProducts, allProducts, editedItems, setEditedItems} = useProduct();

    useEffect(() => {
        async function fetchProducts() {
            const res = await axios.get('https://a.nacapi.com/LimeGreen/products/').catch(err => console.log(err));
            
            if(res) {
            setProducts(res.data)
            setEditedItems(false);
            if(allProducts.length === 0 && editedItems === false) setAllProducts(products);
            if(allProducts.length === 0 && editedItems === true) setAllProducts(allProducts);
            if(allProducts.length > 0) setAllProducts([...allProducts]);
        }
            return res;
        }
        fetchProducts();
        
    }, []);


    return (
      <Wrapper classname="wrapper">
        <h1>All Products</h1>
            <Cards>
                {!!allProducts.length && (
                     allProducts.map(product => (
                        <ProductCard name={product.name} description={product.Description} price={product.Price} discount={product.Discount} key={product.uuid}/>
                    )) 
                )}
             </Cards>
     </Wrapper>
    )
}
```

The context, where I use LocalStorage

```
export const ProductContext = React.createContext();

export function useProduct() {
    return useContext(ProductContext);
}

export function ProductProvider({children}) {
    const [products, setProducts] = useLocalStorage('Api Data', []);
    const [addedProduct, setAddedProduct] = useLocalStorage('Added Item', []);
    const [allProducts, setAllProducts] = useLocalStorage('All Products', []);
    const [editedItems, setEditedItems ] = useLocalStorage('Edited', false);
    const [isAdded, setIsAdded] = useState(false);
    
    const value = {
        products,
        setProducts,
        addedProduct,
        setAddedProduct,
        allProducts,
        setAllProducts,
        editedItems, 
        setEditedItems,
        isAdded,
        setIsAdded,
       
    }

    return (
        <ProductContext.Provider value={value}>
            {children}
        </ProductContext.Provider>
    )
}
```

And Code where I set edit products to true

```
const ProductEdit = () => {

    const {allProducts, setAllProducts, setEditedItems} = useProduct();
    const [editProductId, setEditProductId] = useState(null);
    
    const [editForm, setEditForm] = useState({
        name: "",
        Description: "",
        Price: "",
        Discount: "",
    })

    const saveEditHandler = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        const fieldName = e.target.getAttribute("name");
        const fieldValue = e.target.value;

        const newForm = {...editForm};
        newForm[fieldName] = fieldValue;
        setEditForm(newForm);
    }

    const editHandler = (e, product) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        setEditProductId(product.uuid);

        const formValues = {
            name: product.Name,
            Description: product.Description,
            Price: product.Price,
            Discount: product.Discount
        }

        setEditForm(formValues);
    }

   const submitEditsHandler = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();

        const editedProduct = {
            name: editForm.Name,
            Description: editForm.Description,
            Price: editForm.Price,
            Discount: editForm.Discount,
            uuid: editProductId
        }

        const newProducts = [...allProducts];


        const index = allProducts.findIndex((product) => product.uuid === editProductId);

        newProducts[index] = editedProduct;
        setAllProducts(newProducts);
        setEditedItems(true);
        
        setEditProductId(null);

   }

   const cancelHandler = () => {
       setEditProductId(null);
   }

   const deleteHandler = (productId) => {
    const newProducts = [...allProducts];

    const index = allProducts.findIndex((product) => product.uuid === productId);

    newProducts.splice(index, 1);
   
    setAllProducts(newProducts);
    setEditedItems(true);
  };
```

Comment: You app is not rerendered after you get your data. I believe the issue is in useProduct() function. I think you need to use useState in some way to trigger that render. I don't think that useLocalStorage will trigger it

Comment: @SlothOverlord Using useState instead of useLocalStorage fixed the issue. Thank you!! :)